# Signing multipart/alternative email, what is the toDigest string?

Tags: c#, email, multipart, sign

What is the body part of the following email example that would be used for signing?

```
------=_NextPart_000_005C_01CD9649.B405A420
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="----=_NextPart_001_005D_01CD9649.B405A420"


------=_NextPart_001_005D_01CD9649.B405A420
Content-Type: text/plain;
charset="iso-8859-2"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

test


------=_NextPart_001_005D_01CD9649.B405A420
Content-Type: text/html;
charset="iso-8859-2"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
.....
</html>
------=_NextPart_001_005D_01CD9649.B405A420--

------=_NextPart_000_005C_01CD9649.B405A420
```

I'm using C# email library, that for multipart/alternative email gives error "Hash value is incorrect" when calling:

```
Smime.CheckSignature(true)
```

That means it computes hash value for wrong part of email body.

Answer (score 1):

So, after hours of trying, this is the answer:

```
------=_NextPart_000_005C_01CD9649.B405A420
*Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
*boundary="----=_NextPart_001_005D_01CD9649.B405A420"
*
*
*------=_NextPart_001_005D_01CD9649.B405A420
*Content-Type: text/plain;
*charset="iso-8859-2"
*Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
*
*test
*
*
*------=_NextPart_001_005D_01CD9649.B405A420
*Content-Type: text/html;
*charset="iso-8859-2"
*Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
*
*<html>
*.....
*</html>
*------=_NextPart_001_005D_01CD9649.B405A420--
*
------=_NextPart_000_005C_01CD9649.B405A420
```

Lines starting with * are the message body (string toDigest) to be hashed. Including the new line at the end! So goes here:

```
Smime = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toDigest))
```